# gst-launch: 'SETUP stream 0 and SETUP stream 1'

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch-1.0

When I run `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location='rtspt://localhost:8554/mystream'`, the output suggests that two streams are being established:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtspt://localhost:8554/mystream
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
```

Does anyone know why two streams (stream 0 and stream 1) are needed? Do the two streams carry different data? Is there any way to use just one stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One stream is for video and one stream is for audio. They are not muxed together, but each of them has their own RTP stream.

Comment: I see. Can the audio stream be disabled completely so that no request is even made?

Comment: Probably. You will need to write an application and hook into the appropriate callbacks where media gets exposed. I assume that if you have unconnected pads the client will not request streams for it.